# How to match a regular expression with exactly one digit in it using python regex?

Tags: python

I am trying to match a string with exactly one digit in it. e.g. '5', '4', '3', etc. I am using the `re` library in python to help me use regex.

I have the following three flags that are being set with respective if statements:

```
import re

if re.match(r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', item):
    timeflag = True

if re.match(r'\d{4}', item):
    voltflag = True   

if re.match(r'^\d{1}', item):
    socflag = True
```

Here is the weird part: when I pass an item with a value say `'2754'`, the `socflag` still gets set to `True`, even though it is only supposed to be true when matching a string with only one digit, like `'5'`.

I am suspecting that my regex syntax is incorrect. So, how do I match a one digit string using python regex?

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if `item` is between 0 and 9? As for your regex, just add $ to end it, i.e. `^\d{1}$`.

Comment: I'd like to check if it's between 0 and 5 inclusive

Comment: Try this: `^[0-5]$`

Comment: `if s in ["0","1","2","3","4","5"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it consists of 1 digit and nothing else:

```
re.match('^\d$', item)
```

If it can contain other non-digit characters:

```
re.match('^\D*\d\D*$', item)
```

By starting the regex with `^` you just ensured that the first character of `item` was used in the regex test. By using a `$` at the end you will ensure that the last character of `item` is used in the regex test. By using both `^` and `$` in the way shown you will ensure that *all* the characters of `item` are used in the test.

Your regex allowed any number of things to happen between the first digit being found and the end of the `item` string.

This is great resource for testing your regexs:

https://www.debuggex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments made by user @kaveh.  This is what I got:

[image]

Results:

[image]