# Python: String match is not working with regular expression

Tags: python, dataframe

We are trying to extract rows from a column whose value contains strictly one of the following values `[TC1, TC2, TC3]`. The trick is that some rows also contain the following values `TC12,TC13` etc. We don't want to extract them. Using `str.contains` is not an option in here.

```
Col_1 Col_2 Col_3
  1    A     TC1
  2    B     TC2
  3    C     TC3
  4    D     TC12
  5    D     TC15
  6    D     TC16

Col_1 Col_2 Col_3
  1    A     TC1
  2    B     TC2
  3    C     TC3
```

We used the following commands:

```
df1 = df.loc[df1['Col_3'].str.match("TC\d{1}")]
df1 = df.loc[df1['Col_3'].str.match("TC[1-3]{1}")]
df1 = df.loc[df1['Col_3'].str.match("TC[1,2,3]")]
```

But the problem is that is not working. Instead of returning the first 3 rows, it is returning all of the rows. We don't understand why it's wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match a regular expression with exactly one digit in it using python regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164191/how-to-match-a-regular-expression-with-exactly-one-digit-in-it-using-python-rege)

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"col":['TC1','TC2','TC3','TC12','TC15','TC16']})
print(df[df["col"].str.match(r"^TC\d$")])
```

output

```
   col
0  TC1
1  TC2
2  TC3
```

Explanation: I used `^` and `$` which mean start and end, so it will only detect where there is fullmatch, so-called raw-string so I can use `\d` inside it without need of additional escaping (for more about this see [re docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)). As side note `"TC[1,2,3]"` does not do what you think - if you enumerate characters inside `[` `]` there is no seperator to be used, so `,` is treated as character, so

```
import re
if(re.match("TC[1,2,3]", "TC,")):
   print("match")
else:
   print("no match")
```

output

```
match
```

Comment: You could also use `.fullmatch()` instead. `df["col"].str.fullmatch(r"TC\d")` will not need the `^` and `$`, though they are essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use str.contains -

```
df = df[df.Col_3.str.contains(pat = r'^TC[\d{1}]$')]
```

or via str.match -

```
df = df[df.Col_3.str.match(pat = r'^TC[\d{1}]$')]
```

or via str.fullmatch -

```
df = df[df.Col_3.str.fullmatch(pat = r'^TC[\d{1}]')]
```

or via apply(slow) -

```
import re
df = df[df.Col_3.apply(lambda x : re.match(r'^TC[\d{1}]$', x)).notna()]
```

Comment: OP specifically mentioned that `str.contains` is not an option (though it would still work if you use `^` AND `$`)